# CompanyMstId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditCompanyMsts(Int32)' error In asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I m working with asp.net mvc api

In Database

CompanyMstId primary key

when I m writing Url in browser:

http://localhost:00000/CompanyMsts/EditCompanyMsts/1018

then give an error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'CompanyMstId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditCompanyMsts(Int32)' in 'WebParty.Controllers.CompanyMstsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

```
namespace WebParty.Controllers
{
    public class CompanyMstsController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult EditCompanyMsts(int CompanyMstId)
        {
            var companymst = poly.CompanyMsts.Find(CompanyMstId);
            //var companymst = poly.CompanyMsts.Where(x => x.CompanyMstId == CompanyMstId).First();
            companymstmodel companyrecordupdate = new companymstmodel();

            companyrecordupdate.CompanyCode = companymst.CompanyCode;
            companyrecordupdate.CompanyName = companymst.CompanyName;

             return View(companyrecordupdate);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EditCompanyMsts(companymstmodel companymst)
        {
            var companyupdate = poly.CompanyMsts.Find(companymst.CompanyMstId);

            HttpResponseMessage response = staticvariable.client.PutAsJsonAsync("CompanyMsts", companymst).Result;
            return Json("your record update", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

companymstmodel.cs

```
namespace WebParty.Models
{
    public class companymstmodel
    {
        public int CompanyMstId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CompanyMsts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditCompanyMsts", new { CompanyMstId = item.CompanyMstId })
```

I have a 1018 record and when I m writing this Url in browser

http://localhost:00000/CompanyMsts/EditCompanyMsts/1018

then give an error??

Comment: Name the parameter `id` (not CompanyMstId) and the `1018` will be bound to that parameter.

Comment: The change you just made means you need `?CompanyMstId=1018` instead.

Comment: @madreflection I change my code and still give an error

Comment: You made the wrong change. I said to change the name of the parameter, not the name of the route value.

Comment: @madreflection can u tell me which place need to change??

Comment: `public ActionResult EditCompanyMsts(int id)`  <-- that's the parameter

Comment: @madreflection http://localhost:000/CompanyMsts/EditCompanyMsts?CompanyMstId=1018 that is not work ?? this will be work  why http://localhost:000/CompanyMsts/EditCompanyMsts/1018 can u tell me??

Comment: The earlier edit you made, from `new { id = ... }` to `new { CompanyMstId = ... }` would've required that. It's one or the other, not both. You should roll back that edit. You need to read more about routing and convention-based model binding.